# How to compile different sources from the edited ones in an Android Studio gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm late to the ant -> gradle migration on Android but trying to improve that.
My build process involves preprocessing my whole java source tree and outputting everything to another folder: `build/preprocessed/java`

I managed to do the actual preprocessing with gradle, and include it as a separate task to the actual build, and get it to build, **but** only by using the preprocessed sources as the main source set:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['build/preprocessed/java']
}
```

The problem is that Android Studio now uses this folder for the default sources that I edit, which is of course not what I want. I want to keep editing the files found in `src/main/java`, but compile the preprocessed ones.

Anything that I can find on the subject (which is not a lot), says to change the main source set as described but doesn't address this IDE editor problem.

I've unsuccessfully tried:

- changing the main source set dynamically during the build
- forcing the compiler to get sources from a different location

Any insight on how to do this would be greatly appreciated